# how to create our own private library with xcode

Tags: xcode8

I have written customise controllers in swift in xcode, and with git i have uploaded them on gitlab, now when i'm trying to clone this library with other projects, i had to add all files in xcode to use those files, it's pretty annoying though to add files if we want to use them, is there any other way to overcome this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to maintain library files and add them all at once to your Xcode, follow these steps

1. go to project file -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources
2. and then click on + icon
3. select "Add Other..."
4. Select your folder

Now it will always build your library files along with your project files.

Hope this Helps!!